# Migrating to Exchange 2007 - Outlook Prompting for Credentials

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook, windows-sbs-2008

We are migrating a client from SBS 2008 to a standalone Exchange 2007 server. We have turned off the Exchange services (System Attendant, Transport, and Info Store) from the services console on the SBS server. After doing this a handful of users have experienced the dreaded credential prompt in Outlook. It occurs every time they open Outlook.

It only seems to be happening to users that have Outlook Anywhere configured in Outlook. Now, I know Outlook Anywhere will prompt for credentials if you are not on the LAN, but the users are on the LAN and it's still prompting. Clients are running both Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013.

If we turn the exchange services back on from the SBS server, then the problem goes away. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you migrating from SBS with Exchange 07 **TO** Exchange 2007?  Unless....wait...are you posting this from 2009?  That can't be it...you mention Outlook 2010 and 2013.  Why would you willingly be doing this?

Comment: Oh, and check/verify your Outlook Anywhere / Autodiscover authentication options in Exchange (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997703%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Comment: The SBS server is unstable and we couldn't jump immediately to Exchange 2013 because we had to raise the functional levels and it wouldn't let us. But that is completely besides the point. The real issue is the credential prompting...

Comment: It's set to Basic and the Outlook Anywhere settings are correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: It should be set to NTLM.  If you can't because of your network/firewall then to Basic, NTLM

Comment: Updated it to NTLM, but does not resolve the issue. Thank you, though!

Comment: hrmmm, it definitely should have if the clients are logging into their computer with their domain credentials.  Did you stop and restart the Exchange virtual servers at that point?

Comment: Set server and client to NTLM, then did IISReset. Now it prompts twice instead of once.

Comment: Then something else is weird.  Check the technet article I linked to.  Are they using their domain credentials?  what are the settings on the old server?  What's different between the old Exchange and new regarding Outlook Anywhere settings?  What happens when you test Autoconfig (right click Outlook notification bar icon while holding control, then "Test...")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I got sidetracked with other projects that took priority. But the good news is the issue appears to be solved!

I can't believe I didn't think of this earlier, but I still had an old send connector and receive connecter that belonged to the older server. Once removed the issue went away. Lesson learned, I hope it proves helpful to others!